# UIImage setBackgroundImage working on simulator but not on phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to set the image of a UIButton I have as part of a custom UITableViewCell class to display images.  The images load from a custom UIImageView class that is used to manage downloading and caching of the images.  The method to assign the image to the button is contained within a delegate method for the custom UIImageView that is called when the image has finished loading:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
image = ((LKCCachedImageView *)self.images[arrayIndex]).image;
[(UIButton *)self.buttons[arrayIndex] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This works on the simulator but not on an actual device.

I've had some issues in the past updating the UI in delegate methods as some were not on the main thread but performing `setBackgroundImage` using `dispatch_async` on the main thread does not change the outcome.

Also, if I change `setBackgroundImage` to `setImage` the image displayed on the button is just a blue square.  I'm not sure what to make of the behavior and I haven't seen anyone with anything exactly like mine.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Which library are you using to download/cache images async (if any)? It might be a problem with the file system paths and the device can't get to the cached image. You should log the entire path and see what comes up.

Comment: Also, you don't need to `alloc/init` if you're setting another value after.

Comment: I'm using a class I wrote myself to manage the caching.  I know that the images are loading properly from the cache because I have several other UIImageViews of the same class loading the same image properly, they're just not assigning their images to the image of a UIButton.

Comment: Have you logged that particular image in question to see if its not `nil`? Breakpoint there and check the current state of your variables before and after assigning to the button (also log the button). As as Marcelo said, careful with the multiple instantiations, they may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah, I've put a breakpoint on the `setBackgroundImage` and inspected `image` and it shows the proper image.

Comment: Okay, what happens if you do `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)self.buttons[arrayIndex];`, then see if `button` isn't `nil`. Do debugging sessions on the simulator & device(s), so you can get an idea of what might be different.

Comment: So the button is not nil.  But I realized that I was reading the log of the simulator when I said that the image was not nil.  It exists in the simulator but is nil on the device.  I figured out the solution to my problem though. I had the imageView setting its image using `performSelectorOnMainThread` and the `waitUntilDone` argument was set to `NO`.  When I changed the argument to `YES` the images loaded properly... Teaches me to do a proper debugging session.  Thanks for all the help!